# StackOverflowError when inserting Photo and Coordinates into SQLite DB

Tags: android, sqlite, stack-overflow

This is my first time working with SQLite in the Android environment. I am trying to insert a photo and the coordinates of the user when the photo is taken, into an `SQLite` DB.

It seemed to have worked fine last night **(Home Computer)** when I tried to insert the photo into the DB, no exceptions, although I couldn't find where the tablet was creating the DB, I tried looking in the `data` folder through the File Explorer in Eclipse `DDMS` but there was nothing in there, using the Windows file Explorer I have `Computer\SCH-I905\Tablet\Android\data` with `com.app` etc but my package is not present.

This morning **(Work Computer)** I am getting a fatal `StackOverflowError` exception. Is there something I am doing wrong with my code?? I am converting the image to `byte[]` then storing to the DB as a `Blob`, I am using the `byte[]` instead of converting the `byte[]` to String due to some recommendations I read against `String`s to `Blob`. Any help or recommendation is MUCH appreciated, thanks.

P.S. I don't have anything in my code converting string `toUpperCase()`

---

**Background:**

- Google APIs 12
- Testing on the Samsung Galaxy 10.1 4G LTE Tablet
- I'm developing on two different computers (Home and Work), presently I copy files to a thumb drive then load them into my Workspace and start Eclipse. I have to uninstall the app due to conflicting signatures and then re-run the application through Eclipse.

---

**Here I convert the image to** `byte[]` **then post to database:**

```
public Camera.PictureCallback jpegHandler = new Camera.PictureCallback(){

    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] jpeg, Camera camera ){
        // TODO Work on the image insertion into the database

        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpeg, 0, jpeg.length);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
            byte[] imageBlob = bos.toByteArray();

            UpdateGeoLocation updateGeo = new UpdateGeoLocation(getApplicationContext());

            double picLat = updateGeo.returnlocation.getLatitude();
            double picLng = updateGeo.returnlocation.getLongitude();

            Log.i("imageBlob", "" + imageBlob);
            Log.i("phoLat", "" + picLat);
            Log.i("phoLng", "" + picLng);

            dbControl.open();
            dbControl.addItem(imageBlob, picLat, picLng);
            dbControl.close();

            Log.i("InsertPhotoIntoDB", "WORKED!");
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.e("InsertPhotoIntoDB", "FAILED: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

---

**Here is a snippet of my** `DatabaseHelper.Java`

```
public class GlobalDBVars {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "NST.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "photos_withCoordinates";

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_PHOTOS = "_photo";
    public static final String KEY_LAT = "_lat";
    public static final String KEY_LNG = "_lng";
}

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + 
    GlobalDBVars.TABLE_NAME + "(" + 
    GlobalDBVars.KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
    GlobalDBVars.KEY_PHOTOS + " BLOB NOT NULL, " + 
    GlobalDBVars.KEY_LAT + " REAL NOT NULL, " + 
    GlobalDBVars.KEY_LNG + " REAL NOT NULL);";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        onCreate(db);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate db: " + DATABASE_CREATE);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "FAILED: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

---

**Insert statement within** `DatabaseControl.Java`

```
public long addItem(byte[] photos, double _lat, double _lng) {
    ContentValues setUpVals = createContentValues(photos, _lat, _lng);

    return database.insert(GlobalDBVars.TABLE_NAME, null, setUpVals);
}
```

---

**LogCat:**

```
09-04 10:08:48.160: I/imageBlob(21529): [B@40751c18
09-04 10:08:48.160: I/phoLat(21529): 37.3674153
09-04 10:08:48.160: I/phoLng(21529): -77.4001403
09-04 10:08:48.240: I/dalvikvm(21529): threadid=1: stack overflow on call to Ljava/util/Locale;.getLanguage:L
09-04 10:08:48.240: I/dalvikvm(21529):   method requires 8+20+0=28 bytes, fp is 0x58f53318 (24 left)
09-04 10:08:48.240: I/dalvikvm(21529):   expanding stack end (0x58f53300 to 0x58f53000)
09-04 10:08:48.240: I/dalvikvm(21529): Shrank stack (to 0x58f53300, curFrame is 0x58f56d8c)
09-04 10:08:48.240: D/AndroidRuntime(21529): Shutting down VM
09-04 10:08:48.240: W/dalvikvm(21529): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40105760)
09-04 10:08:48.270: D/dalvikvm(21529): GC_CONCURRENT freed 95K, 8% free 8606K/9287K, paused 2ms+2ms
09-04 10:08:48.310: E/AndroidRuntime(21529): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 10:08:48.310: E/AndroidRuntime(21529): java.lang.StackOverflowError
09-04 10:08:48.310: E/AndroidRuntime(21529):    at java.lang.CaseMapper.toUpperCase(CaseMapper.java:143)
09-04 10:08:48.310: E/AndroidRuntime(21529):    at java.lang.String.toUpperCase(String.java:1619)
09-04 10:08:48.310: E/AndroidRuntime(21529):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.getSqlStatementType(DatabaseUtils.java:1245)
09-04 10:08:48.310: E/AndroidRuntime(21529):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:100)
09-04 10:08:48.310: E/AndroidRuntime(21529):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:59)
09-04 10:08:48.310: E/AndroidRuntime(21529):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1931)
09-04 10:08:48.310: E/AndroidRuntime(21529):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1864)
09-04 10:08:48.310: E/AndroidRuntime(21529):    at sompackage.nst.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:49)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `onCreate()` recursively

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        **onCreate(db);**
...
}
```

Remove that `onCreate(db)` call

Comment: ugh, so frustrating, it is always these little things. Thanks! That line was suppose to be in my `onUpgrade()` and I placed it in the wrong method. Taken care of and works. Thanks again. I'll accept as soon as I am able.

Answer (score -1):

Revolving call onCreate(db)。

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
try {
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, unless you can provide reference for it.